# REST API: variable path variables

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I create a single REST API for variable number of path variables such as `GET "/ads/{category1}/.../{categoryN}"` in Spring?

where number of categories is not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not provided out-of-the-box by Spring, but there is some workaround.

You can map any path like "/ads/**" to your handler method, and then parse categories by splitting the rest of the path by slash:

```
String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
String tailPath = path.substring(5); //skip "/ads/"
String[] categories = tailPath.split("/");
```